# Maven Surefire Test Rerun Parameter Does Not Re-Run Failing Tests

Tags: java, maven, junit, maven-surefire-plugin

Maven surefire does not rerun failing tests. I tried to change the surefire version to 3.0.0-M4, 3.0.0-M5. Use commandline option -Dsurefire.rerunFailingTestsCount=3, added <surefire.rerunFailingTestsCount>2</surefire.rerunFailingTestsCount> to the pom file, and added 2 to the configurations of surefire plugin; ran mvn install multiple times. However, nothing seems to work and Surefire runs failing tests just once. The pom file of the project I am working with is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.authy</groupId>
    <artifactId>authy-java</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.1</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <name>Authy Java</name>
    <description>Java library to access the Authy API.</description>
    <url>https://github.com/authy/authy-java</url>

    <licenses>
        <license>
            <name>The MIT License (MIT)</name>
            <url>https://github.com/authy/authy-java/blob/master/LICENSE.txt</url>
        </license>
    </licenses>

    <developers>
        <developer>
            <name>Sergio Aristizabal</name>
            <email>saristizabal@twilio.com</email>
            <organization>Twilio</organization>
            <organizationUrl>http://www.twilio.com</organizationUrl>
        </developer>
    </developers>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <scm>
        <connection>scm:git:git@github.com:authy/authy-java.git</connection>
        <developerConnection>scm:git:git@github.com:authy/authy-java.git</developerConnection>
        <url>git@github.com:authy/authy-java.git</url>
    </scm>


                <dependencies>
                    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hamcrest/hamcrest-core -->
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
                        <artifactId>hamcrest-core</artifactId>
                        <version>2.2</version>
                        <scope>test</scope>
                    </dependency>


                    <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jetty-server</artifactId>
                    <version>9.4.44.v20210927</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.github.ben-manes.caffeine</groupId>
                    <artifactId>caffeine</artifactId>
                    <version>2.5.5</version>
                </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.github.ben-manes.caffeine</groupId>
                    <artifactId>caffeine</artifactId>
                    <version>2.5.5</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
                    <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
                    <version>1.10.19</version>
                </dependency>
                
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>json</artifactId>
            <version>20150729</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.11</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.tomakehurst</groupId>
            <artifactId>wiremock</artifactId>
            <version>2.11.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <distributionManagement>
        <snapshotRepository>
            <id>ossrh</id>
            <name>Authy Maven Snapshot Repository</name>
            <url>
                https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/
            </url>
        </snapshotRepository>

        <repository>
            <id>ossrh</id>
            <name>Authy Maven Repository</name>
            <url>
                https://oss.sonatype.org/service/local/staging/deploy/maven2/
            </url>
        </repository>

    </distributionManagement>

    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>release</id>
            <activation>
                <property>
                    <name>performRelease</name>
                    <value>true</value>
                </property>
            </activation>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
      <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>2.19.1</version>
      <configuration>
    <rerunFailingTestsCount>2</rerunFailingTestsCount>
</configuration>
    </plugin>

                    <plugin>
                                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                                <version>2.3.2</version>
                                <executions>
                                    <execution>
                                        <id>default-testCompile</id>
                                        <phase>test-compile</phase>
                                        <goals>
                                            <goal>testCompile</goal>
                                        </goals>
                                        <configuration combine.self="override">
                                            <skip>true</skip>
                                        </configuration>
                                    </execution>
                                </executions>
                            </plugin>
                        <plugin>
                            <groupId>edu.illinois.cs</groupId>
                            <artifactId>testrunner-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                            <version>1.2</version>
                            <dependencies>
                                <dependency>
                                    <groupId>edu.illinois.cs</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>idflakies</artifactId>
                                    <version>1.2.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
                                </dependency>
                            </dependencies>
                            <configuration>
                                <className>edu.illinois.cs.dt.tools.detection.DetectorPlugin</className>
                            </configuration>
                        </plugin>
                        
                        <plugin>
                            <groupId>edu.illinois</groupId>
                            <artifactId>nondex-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                            <version>1.1.2</version>
                        </plugin>
                        
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-gpg-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>1.5</version>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <id>sign-artifacts</id>
                                <phase>verify</phase>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>sign</goal>
                                </goals>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <autoVersionSubmodules>true</autoVersionSubmodules>
                    <useReleaseProfile>false</useReleaseProfile>
                    <!-- references the profile defined just below -->
                    <releaseProfiles>release</releaseProfiles>
                    <goals>deploy</goals>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.2.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>attach-sources</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>jar</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.9.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>attach-javadocs</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>jar</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.sonatype.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>nexus-staging-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.6.3</version>
                <extensions>true</extensions>
                <configuration>
                    <serverId>ossrh</serverId>
                    <nexusUrl>https://oss.sonatype.org/</nexusUrl>
                    <autoReleaseAfterClose>true</autoReleaseAfterClose>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>cobertura-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.7</version>
                <configuration>
                    <formats>
                        <format>html</format>
                        <format>xml</format>
                    </formats>
                    <check />
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

I am a little bit lost what might be causing the failing tests to be executed multiple times as I tried a lot of different suggestions on stackoverflow.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

There are some missing configurations under maven-surfire-plugin. Please, have a look at the working configuration:

```
                     <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>${maven-surefire-plugin.version}</version>
                        <configuration>
                            <includes>
                                <include>**/TestRunner.java</include>
                            </includes>
                            <argLine>
                                -javaagent:"${settings.localRepository}/org/aspectj/aspectjweaver/${org.aspectj.version}/aspectjweaver-${org.aspectj.version}.jar"
                            </argLine>
                            <rerunFailingTestsCount>${rerunCount}</rerunFailingTestsCount>
                        </configuration>
                        <dependencies>
                            <dependency>
                                <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
                                <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
                                <version>${org.aspectj.version}</version>
                            </dependency>
                            <dependency>
                                <groupId>org.apache.maven.surefire</groupId>
                                <artifactId>surefire-junit47</artifactId>
                                <version>${maven-surefire-plugin.version}</version>
                            </dependency>
                        </dependencies>
                    </plugin>
```